# Semantic Model, Adaptive Model and DSLs

Tags: terminology, dsl

I was reading about DSLs (Martin Fowler's book) and in the first chapter he talks about Semantic and Adaptive models. I dont really understand what these terms mean in the context of  DSLs. I tried searching and reading more about them but I still dont quite get it since the explanations are also kind of complex. I would really appreciate if someone could explain these to me in simple terms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both patterns explained in a bit more detail later in the same book and have links in Fowler's on-line [DSL Pattern Catalog](http://martinfowler.com/dslCatalog/index.html) (though these provide little information beyond pointers to the locations in the book).  Semantic Model is detailed in Chapter 11 and Adaptive Model is in Chapter 47.

Basically, a Semantic Model is a model tightly tied to the language, describing the same domain of knowledge that the language does, is created pretty directly by the parser.  Using one is generally recommended for separating  the parsing logic from the semantic logic.

Adaptive Model is a technique for defining an alternative computational model (i.e., a computational model not normally done in the host language), and is sometimes actually a Semantic Model modeling a computational DSL.